# Angular 5 - Constructor and ngOnInit are not executed

Tags: angular, angular5, sortablejs

I am using Angular 5 in combination with SortableJs.

On a page I have listed multiple cards grouped.

HTML looks like

```
<div class="group" *ngFor="let group of groups" [sortablejs]="group.cards" [sortablejsOptions]="sortableOptions">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let card of group.cards">
        <button routerLink="card/edit/{{card.id}}">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I move a card from one group to another and I click on edit button it will redirect me to a page where I can edit the selected card.

When it redirects me to that page the constructor and ngOnInit are not executed.

After I click an element, those two execute.

Update: Plunker code: https://embed.plnkr.co/mCJGo60sxQLQohWRYC3O/

EDIT: To see the problem you need to move one button from one group to another then click the same button you moved. You will see that the binding are not done.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with a JSFiddle? It would increase your chances of getting a (good) answer.

Comment: Can you edit your post so we can see the component in which ngOnInit is no executed, and the component calling

Comment: Sure. Just give ma a few minutes

Comment: Here is the plunker code. https://embed.plnkr.co/mCJGo60sxQLQohWRYC3O/

Comment: I just checked. Both the constructor and onInit are working. Where is the problem?

Comment: Try to move a button from a group to another then click one of the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When routing, if only the params of your router link are changing, (In your case :card.id) Angular will not destroy and recreate your component.

Angular destroys and recreates component only if your original route changes.

Hence onInit is not being called.

If you need the card.id in your component, you can subscribe to the params like this:

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.params.subscribe(val => {
    console.log("Button ID: " + val.id);
  });
}
```

Note that you need to import and inject ActivatedRoute in your card edit component.

Entire code for app-component:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { SortablejsModule, SortablejsOptions } from 'angular-sortablejs';
import { Routes, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class App {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cards',
  template: `
  <p> Try to move buttons </p>
   <div class="group" *ngFor="let group of groups" [sortablejs]="group.cards" [sortablejsOptions]="sortableOptions">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let card of group.cards">
        <button routerLink="card/edit/{{card.id}}">Edit {{card.id}}</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
  `,
})
export class Cards {
  groups = [
    {
      id: 1,
      cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      cards: [
        {
          id: 4,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  sortableOptions: SortablejsOptions = {
    group: 'checks'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-card-edit',
  template: `
  <p routerLink="">Go Home</p>
  <p>{{content}}</p>
  <input type="text" value="{{content}}">
  `,
})
export class CardEdit implements OnInit {
  content = "content here";

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(val => {
     console.log("Button ID: " + val.id);
    });
  }



}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    SortablejsModule.forRoot({
      animation: 0,
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: Cards},
      {path: 'card/edit/:id', component: CardEdit}
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ App, Cards, CardEdit ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It works for the buttons I did't moved. Try move a button and click on it. Also this is a useful comment

Comment: Thank you. I see that it works in a manner. But the main problem now is why it doesn't the bindings?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani Did you figured out the issue? I am not using route change instead giving an input to a component but component is not detecting the change. Hence not updating the view. Not sure what is wrong neither ngOnInit fires and constructor. This fires only when i click on that page. Eventually after clicking Input or ngOnChanges is also getting fired. please let me know if you found any real solution

Comment: @Deepender , can you please create a new question with your code on it. I can't figure out without the code :)

Comment: Sure will do that

Comment: @VinodBhavnani The code is very big, with small piece of chunks, I tried to explain my issue. Hope you will get the idea 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540603/sortablejs-onadd-of-element-input-to-a-component-is-not-changing